# Common color associations and movie genres

Tags: color-scheme, intuition

For others:

My Question got answered, but in a different way. The answer basically is that:

- it wouldn't make much of a difference and
- That "We have (...) standards like Red for love, passion,violence and Blue for calm,serene,corporate etc. Grey for war, Red for drama, Dark green for horror do not really help the user make that association."

Big thank you to [Shreyas Tripathy](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/97993/shreyas-tripathy)

---

I have an app that contains different Movies and so there are different Movie Genres. The user can click on a movie and get more information about it (Description, Details, Actors,...)

What I would like to achieve/do is that if the user opens up the Detail View the Background should slightly change, depending on the genre of the movie (Colors are a strong way to set the mood for something, and if the color matches the association to that genre, that would set a comfortable mood - I guess)
(I know there can not be a definite answer, but there must be a common practice):

(Is there a common practice to color a Movie Genre? p.E.: Do Movie Posters follow a common practice, like: Romance Movies mostly are red, Sci-Fi mostly white, War mostly brown,...? Or is there nothing like this and I have to go for own associations?)

p.E Like:

- Action (Blue)
- Adventure (Green)
- Comedy (Yellow)
- Crime & Gangster (Purple)
- Drama (Red)
- Historical (Gold)
- Horror (DarkGreen)
- Musicals (Orange)
- Sci-Fi (Silver)
- War (Grey)
- Western (Brown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I feel. Color coding is very good way of setting the mood but overusing it makes the concept lose its purpose. Here's why:

- The idea behind color coding is to set a tone the application/environment/website/etc. You want the user to be able to associate a color with a concept but if there are too many colors, the brain wouldn't want to make those associations as it is too gruesome.
- **Standards** - We have some standards like Red for love, passion,violence and Blue for calm,serene,corporate etc. However, Grey for war, Red for drama, Dark green for horror aren't that standard or obvious. Hence, they do not really help the user make that association.

**Should you do it?** 
That would be up to you now because I feel like it won't have the utility you want it to have but maybe you can use it as a feature while pitching your product.

Comment: So having  "grey-ish" main Colors like '#f2f2f2', '#161616' ,...  and only one blue Main-Color would not go well with my "idea", I guess? - Basically it is not worth it, because it would't make much of an impact?

Comment: @DanielMaurer - I am sorry I don't follow. You're calling the greys your *main* colors and then the blue as the *main* color too. Could you clarify?

Comment: I am sorry blue is my accent color (for Highlights,..). The UI consist of decent colors and I have blue as my accent color. I wanted the UI to not get much attention but the content to stick out and set the mood. - A bad idea? This is my first bigger project.

Comment: @DanielMaurer - Understood. I want to make sure that my answer didn't create any confusion between color scheme and color tone (just wanted to get that out of the way)

You color scheme seems fine to me. You have the dark grey as a background and the light grey as menu background or vice versa. Blue is the accent color. You can easily have hover or active state colors picked from the various blue tones. Was this your concern?

Comment: As far as focus on the content is concerned, do what most movie/video related sites do. Have the movie poster as the background of the detail view container. That would stick out of the dark/light background and you won't have to worry about your website looking like a traffic light

Comment: I guess I was/am a bit afraid that everything would end up too blend. Is it a good idea to let the content set the mood? Or would it end up too chaotic. (In future there will be many different movies (therefore many different Movies Posters) - Like in Spotify.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the album views of music apps like iTunes and Groove Music and app stores for getting an idea about spacing between each movie title's tile. Keep the background bland to make sure that the focus is on the movie tile. The posters would add enough color already and yes, that would make the layout chaotic.

I am not a fan of what Netflix does when a video tile is clicked. The background isn't translucent which makes the layout very unnerving. I'd suggest you avoid that.

Comment: Oh wow Groove Music looks really nice! I guess you helped me out! Thank you. Sadly I can not upvote .. yet (well it just won't be visible).

Comment: Glad I could help